# How to sync with pivot id in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.6, and I have these tables in my database:

```
attributes table: id, name

attribute_values: id, attribute_id, value

products: id, name
```

My query is that how can I save `pivot` in **table:field** `attribute:id` along with **table:field** `attribute_value:id` and **table:field** `product:id` using `sync` in `attribute_value_product` table?

## Further details:

**attribute model:**

```
public function attributevalues(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Model\AttributeValue');
    }
```

**attribute value model:**

```
public function attributes(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Attribute', 'attribute_id');
    }
```

**product model:**

```
public function attributes(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\Attribute', 'attribute_products');
    }

    public function attributeValues(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\AttributeValue', 'attribute_value_products');
    }
```

**product controller:**

```
$product->save();
$product->attributes()->sync($request->attribute);
```

Having given all the required details, now I want is to know, what changes should I make in the following line to be able to solve my problem :-

```
$product->attributeValues()->sync($request->attribute_value);
```

Comment: Can you please go through : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7s0kzx4IxCA, and see whether you have answer to your problem. It will be my pleasure if it helps.